# How to make required work on a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

My custom directive looks like

```
    <cities-directive name="cities" ng-model="obj.cities" required></cities-directive>
```

The required directive does not work. Initially obj.cities is an empty array. How do I make it compulsory for the user to select at least one city so that obj.cities is not an empty array? Basically this directive is inside a ng-form and I dont want the form to be submitted if the array is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_required.asp) , you can only use required on 3 types oh html markup :

1. TextArea
2. Input
3. Select

For what you are trying to do, there are some basic solution :

- If your custom directive template consists in an input, then you can try to modify your directive so you can use it as an attribute or a class and not as an element. (See A, E and C restrictions). Then apply your directive to a select or input markup.
- You can simply use ngDisabled on the button of your form submit to prevent the user to send the form if obj.cities is empty.

```html
<form>
    <button ng-disabled="obj.cities.isEmpty()"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I cant do the first option. Is there a way to achieve this within the directive? I have read elsewhere about ngModel and how it can be used for validation but cant find an example in jsbin or plunkr.

Comment: Have you tried to put the required attribute directly into the template from the directive ? Ie if you use an input in the directive template, then put required into this tag directly. It might help if you give your directive code, especially the html template

Comment: Thanks Alburkerk...Yeah thats not an option cause in my directive. When cities array is empty the multi select shows nothing...when the user adds cities the multi select starts populating. Required on multi select means the user has clicked on one of those options. For my form if cities exist in multi select then its valid

Comment: Yeah that's the purpose of required which is not adapted to your form. For that the ngDisabled is the best solution I think. Does it fix your problem ?

Comment: That should work but I want a solution that involves ngModel to make it consistent with other elements on the form.

Comment: For this you can change the $error property of the form directly when the ng-model is empty. Adding the error should prevent the form to be submitted and also enable the display of a custom error message. More infos here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Comment: Thanks a lot Alburkerk..that worked...for anyone facing the same issue I did require: ['^form', 'ngModel'] in the directive  and  inside link function                       ctrls[0].cities.$error.required = true;
ctrls[0].$invalid = true;  cities is the name of my directive and I got ctrls[0] from the fourth argument of my link function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls)